# Consulta - Mostrar datos de tabla relacionada

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach

tengo una duda. Quiero mostrar los colores disponibles de un producto. Hice dos tablas distintas y las relacioné por medio del Id.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Con esto ya podré mostrar los colores disponibles de cada equipo, dependiendo de lo que yo haya agregado.
- Lo que quiero hacer es algo similar a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- En esa imagen tengo mis dos productos y quiero mostrar los colores disponibles, estoy usando PHP (PDO) y MYSQL, y en realidad no se cómo imprimir los datos en pantalla, exactamente hablo de los colores, ya que a cada producto le corresponde diferentes colores, asimismo cómo puedo editar dichos colores y eliminarlos. Al momento puedo mostrar los productos (nombre, imagen, precio, etc), usando FOREACH, en pantalla, y puedo almacenar en MYSQL los datos pero no se cómo mostrar según el producto lo colores que están disponibles, necesito la ayuda de ustedes muchas gracias.  :)

Comment: En el FOREACH de productos podrías hacer un query a la tabla de colores y con otro FOREACH mostrarlos.

Comment: Pero yo veo un problema en tu diseño de datos. ¿El id que se ve en la tabla colores es el del producto? Si es así, mal, muy mal. Si hay `500` productos con el color `rojo` tendrás que tener `500` filas en esa tabla repitiendo el campo `color=rojo` por cada `id`de producto. Aquí aplicaría una relación: *uno a muchos*, o sea, *muchos `productos` pueden tener un mismo `color`*, en ese caso, la relación tiene que ser creando en la tabla `producto` una columna `id_color`. Primero tienes que corregir el diseño de datos, luego podemos pasar a la forma de consultarlos.

Comment: Si por el contrario, *varios `productos` pueden tener varios `colores`*, la relación sería del tipo *muchos a muchos*. Ese tipo de relaciones se expresan en una tercera tabla, que se llama tabla asociativa. En ese caso, no tienes que tener `id_color` en la tabla `producto`, ni tampoco tener `id_producto` en la tabla `color`, sino que creas una tabla llamada `producto_color` con dos columnas: `id_producto, id_color` y allí por cada producto-color creas una fila. Esto se hace para evitar la redundancia de datos en las otras tablas, ya que expresar esa relación en las tablas sería repetir datos.